# What will we do if Imgur closes?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

All images are hosted on Imgur. What will happen if they close? And their host crashes.

Many questions have very important images for many purposes. I was just wondering if the site is prepared?

Comment: what happens if the data center of Stack Overflow burned to ashes in an short circuit or destroyed in a Tsunami or earthquake? There are many such probabilities. But I hope they have a backup of that images

Comment: @SagarV lets hope it doesn't come to that :)

Comment: @SagarV they already had a Tsunami once, kind of, http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/31/an-update-on-sandy/

Comment: Hold a funeral for Reddit?